# ADC on RPi always produces same value

Tags: pi-3b+, mcp3008

https://stackoverflow.com/q/63606134/14167364
Please follow the link for my original post was in python forum.

[image]

I have a moisture sensor and it uses analog so I purchased MCP3008 ADC. I have installed all the packages, ensured the SPI is enabled, checked multiple MCP3008 chips, ran 2 separate python scripts for this, used multiple sensors and made sure they work by simply letting it read digital signal as I place it in water and it changes from 1 to 0, i quadruple checked all my plug-ins, and checked every channel in the MCP chip, and used meter to ensure continuity. So, I have done pretty much everything I can think of and I am getting the same max value no matter what. I can't figure out what is wrong. Is there anything I can try that I haven't?

To conclude, the problem is that I always get the same value in my output regardless of channel, sensor, chip, or py script used. Here is one example script.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import busio
import digitalio
import board
import adafruit_mcp3xxx.mcp3008 as MCP
from adafruit_mcp3xxx.analog_in import AnalogIn

# create the spi bus
spi = busio.SPI(clock=board.SCK, MISO=board.MISO, MOSI=board.MOSI)

# create the cs (chip select)
cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D22)

# create the mcp object
mcp = MCP.MCP3008(spi, cs)
print(mcp)

# create an analog input channel on pin 0
chan0 = AnalogIn(mcp, MCP.P1)

print('Raw ADC Value: ', chan0.value)
print('ADC Voltage: ' + str(chan0.voltage) + 'V')
```

this always prints... Raw ADC Value: 65472 ADC Voltage: 3.2968276493476765V[image]
[image]

You will notice the orange wire on the RPi is in different locations for the 2 bottom pictures. This was because I was trying out a different method from a tutorial I saw. Neither setup worked as intended though. If you see anything wrong, please let me know. Otherwise, I will start much smaller as suggested and work my way up.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112337/discussion-on-question-by-justin-oberle-adc-on-rpi-always-produces-same-value).

Comment: Please also use this opportunity to edit in relevant information to your question. Since you're new here I recommend you take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com//tour) to find out how the site works.